# Best Practice in Python: Class Object with helper variables - delete helpers after use

Tags: python

I want to have a Class with only one argument to it. Based on that argument a couple of calculations should take place aiming at setting a specific attribute for the Class. Other attributes won't be needed afterwards and I would like to delete them within the Class. What's the best approach?

Simplified Example:

```
class Sportsteam:
    def __init__(self, members):
        self.members = members # members will be a list
        self.num_members = len(self.members) # helpler variable: how many team members are in the sportsteam?
        self.rooms = math.ceil(self.num_members/2) # how many doubles will be needed in a hotel?
```

I want to delete the instance variable `num_members` because it won't be needed afterwards. I want that to be done within the class/object, so I do not need a separate line with `del instance.num_members` within my script for each instance.

*Please note that variable assigning is more complex with a lot of conditions in the original use case. Calculation without the helper-variable would work in the example above, but would be really annoying in the use case.*

Comment: It doesn't have to be a field, just leave it as a local variable.

Comment: Thanks! I did not now that you can use local variables within the `__init__` statement. Did not see that in any example online as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @monk pointed out, also local variables can be assigned within the `__init__` statement. For above example the use of a helper variable would therefor be:

```
class Sportsteam:
    def __init__(self, members):
        self.members = members # members will be a list
        num_members = len(self.members) # helper variable: how many team members are in the sportsteam?
        self.rooms = math.ceil(num_members/2) # how many doubles will be needed in a hotel?
```

In this case `instance.num_members` does not exist.

*I was researching for an answer to my question with different keywords for quite a while, but neither came to a solution nor to an example which showed that possibility*